# How passing an argument to a function

Tags: python

Why doesn't this work?
What would it take for this to work?

```
call = 'Duster'
def text(call):
    print(call)

text()
```

Answer (score 4):

The **call** inside your function and **call** outside your function are utterly independent variables.  You have to pass things through the parameter list.

```
call = 'Duster'
def text(call):
    print(call)

text(call)
```

Actually, you *can* use a *global* variable, but please avoid those.

To illustrate this better, move the lines of your main program together and change the names:

```
def text(phrase):
    print(phrase)

name = 'Duster'
text(name)
```

Also, the main program of two lines could be just one line:

```
text('Duster')
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the argument named `call` takes precedence over the variable named `call` due to scoping.

You could make this work by using your code and just changing the last line

```
text(call)
```

Or you could use the variable directly and not an argument

```
call = 'Duster'
def text():
    print(call)

text()
```